# Unable to launch application using Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to create a new keyboard shortcut to launch Android Studio or Netbeans, but don't know if it is possible.

I've added a new keyboard shortcut and changed the command to:
**cd /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin && ./netbeans**

This command works in the terminal, but doesn't want to work as a keyboard shortcut. Please can you help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys. I've figured it out. I had to change the command to **/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans**. This works for bo